# Linux alternatives to Team Viewer?

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-access, xrdp, rdp

I'm wondering if there are any open-source applications or services that run on Linux and can provide remote access over port 80? I don't specifically need graphics, so it could just be SSH/shell access. But I'm in a situation where I'll have multiple Linux machines each behind the same router, plus I won't have access to that router to set up port forwarding anyway. I'm kind of envisioning something like [Team Viewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/), but having used TV on Linux their program is garbage. Are there any programs that can operate over port 80 and ping some central, external server for remote access?

Comment: Do you really need an open-source application? If not, anydesk.com may do the job for you. Uses port 80 and there is a free version available.

Comment: True, it doesn't need to be open source, strictly speaking. Would love to use Anydesk however the devices I'll be running this on have ARM architectures which is not supported by Anydesk, as far as I know.

Comment: No Anydesk does not support ARM. They've said they are working on porting to ARM but no date given...